# How to perform sign off (logout) from react-native-azure-ad-2 in react native?

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Currently I have implemented react-native-azure-ad-2 in react native. I want to add logout functionality to it because there is no option to change to another user when user is already logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a ADLoginView has prop needLogout set to true it redirect user to
>   AD logout page for logout.

```
<ADLoginView
              context={ReactNativeAD.getContext(CLIENT_ID)}
              needLogout={true}/>
```

I found this [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-azure-ad#user-content-logout), but this is react-native-azure-ad. You can have a try.